# how to eliminate dead space on ggplot facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I eliminate the dead space on my facet panels below? I want months 10-12 *dead space* eliminated on panel "A" and months 1-9 *dead space*  eliminated from panel "B".

I don't want to use manual methods as I have a lot of data that changes frequently. I also need the panels to scale properly to each other. Panel "A" should be three times the length of panel "B" since it's x-axis contains nine values whereas panel "B"'s x-axis only contains three values.

Ideally panel "B" should just look like a continuation where panel "A" gets left off.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggQC)

# Create the data frame
set.seed(5555)
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month = 1:12,
                            egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.2), 
                            group = c(rep("A", 9), rep("B", 3)))

#>  month egg_diameter group
#>      1     1.346167     A
#>      2     1.410460     A
#>      3     1.219141     A
#>      4     1.578410     A
#>      5     1.648865     A
#>      6     1.207796     A
#>      7     1.490460     A
#>      8     1.330943     A
#>      9     1.431585     A
#>     10     1.433876     B
#>     11     1.673110     B
#>     12     1.632368     B

# Plot data frame on a control chart
XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR") + 
  facet_grid(~group)
XmR_Plot
```

[image: this is the plot, I'm not sure why it's not showing inline]

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the `scales` argument in `facet_grid`? Specifically, `scales = "free_x"`?

Comment: ...although if you really want the display to act as a continuous graph between the two groups, I would suggest trying something other than faceting. Maybe plot everything on one panel, and distinguish the two groups using background shading via `geom_rect`?

Comment: @joran `scales = "free_x"` almost does it, the scale (pardon the pun) is just off. Panel "A" and "B" are the same size giving the illusion they cover the same time period. But "A" is nine months and "B" is only three months. I'd try `geom_rect` as long as it still draws the control limits (red lines) correctly.

Comment: @JasonHunter Can you try `+ facet_grid(~group, scales = "free", space = "free")`

Comment: @markus that pretty much does what I want, can you post as an answer and (if you could) fix the x-axis scaling so they're both single integer increases (ie month 1, 2, 3, 4, etc), which I assume would also set the gridlines to match (in the background) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the argument `space = "free"` in `facet_grid`

```
XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR") + 
  facet_grid(~group, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12,
                     labels = month.abb # delete this (and the comma in the line above) if you want numbers
                     )
XmR_Plot
```

[image]